# One to many where all relations exist

Tags: mysql, join, one-to-many

Let's say I have three MySQL tables:

```
╔═════════════════╗     ╔════════════╗     ╔══════════════════════╗
║     animals     ║     ║   colors   ║     ║     animal_color     ║
╠════╦════════════╣     ╠════╦═══════╣     ╠═══════════╦══════════╣
║ id ║    name    ║     ║ id ║ name  ║     ║ animal_id ║ color_id ║
╠════╬════════════╣     ╠════╬═══════╣     ╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ Panther    ║     ║  1 ║ black ║     ║         1 ║        1 ║
║  2 ║ Zebra      ║     ║  2 ║ white ║     ║         2 ║        1 ║
║  3 ║ Polar bear ║     ║  3 ║ blue  ║     ║         2 ║        2 ║
╚════╩════════════╝     ╚════╩═══════╝     ║         3 ║        2 ║
                                           ╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Each animal can have one or more colors assigned to it. How would I look for an animal that has both **black** and **white** color assigned (zebra)? I know there are multiple ways to do it, but what are some simple ones? Perhaps without any subqueries?

I came out with something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   `animals`
WHERE  `id` IN (SELECT `animal_id`
                FROM   `animal_color`
                WHERE  `color_id` IN ( 1, 2 )
                GROUP  BY `animal_id`
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

But I feel like it's clumsy and I also don't like that I need to count the number of colors I'm interested in.

It seems like there is some simple way to do it.

**UPDATE**

It would be great to know simple ways to both versions of this problem:

1. Selecting animal that is black and white **without any other color**
2. Selecting animal that is black, white **and possibly more colors, but not necessarily**

Comment: Technically, if an animal was assigned the same colour twice (such as white), your query would still pick it up as being black and white, because the count would be 2.

Comment: @Noman It is `INNER JOIN`. In MySQL, `JOIN` is just shorter way to say `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: If I went with count I would add some filter on colors (so that if you added e.g. green it wouldn't affect the result) and added DISTINCT to count. EDIT: Ok, I just noticed you are filtering colors :)

Comment: @Andrew Yeah I know that. While I would prevent it with a composite unique index, I don't like this fact neither :)

Comment: @TedHopp I edited it, sorry.

Comment: Do you also want animals with more than 2 colors as long as two of those are black and white?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's actually a great question and I would love to see both solutions! I will update my question.

Comment: Well your sample return any animals with at least black and white colors... my answer return only black and white animals. That is why there are different.  So please remove that "worse than mine" comment (very rude btw)

Comment: Because I don't see any point in using this query. I asked for a simple one, I can think of many clunky queries for this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have too bad of a method, along with the unique index you mention to ensure the result is correct.

There is a 'simpler' version without sub queries - you can join twice to animal colour, once for black, once for white - it would self-filter, but this method is not extensible to cover 3 colours animal queries etc, so I'm not keen on it as a solution.

As long as the query plan your SQL produces is efficient, and the meaning of the query is obvious / maintainable, that should be sufficient. Those should be the goals of the SQL statement.

Comment: I was thinking about the separate subqueries, but for sake of simplicity, I'd love the idea to have it easy for quering, because my project will allow to select many colors and making separate subquery for each feels funny :)

Comment: Per colour you are checking existence of a row, whether through exists clauses / sub-queries, or a single sub-query it will have to flex depending on the number of values you are looking for. You could insert the colours into a temp table and then join from that potentially as an alternative mechanism to avoid the IN clause expansions you can expect when handling multiple different combinations of colours

Comment: What's wrong with IN clause expansion? I thought it's more efficient that multiple subqueries.

Comment: For small number of items it is not too bad, for a large number it gets problematic - your example is unlikely to grow too large. Depending on how you implement it though, you may be creating dynamic SQL and not using a procedure - that itself is less desirable. This though is going off topic for the question a bit and is more about SQL Standards and practices, not the specifics of the query.

Comment: Andrew, that's very interesting, I didn't know about that. In my example I expect maximum of, let's say, ~10 colors in one query.

Answer (score 0):

For animals with black and white colours:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM animals a
INNER JOIN animal_color ac ON (a.id = ac.animal_id)
INNER JOIN colors c ON (ac.color_id = c.id AND c.name IN ('black', 'white'))
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ac.color_id) = 2
```

That being said, your method is not inherently "incorrect". Using joins to filter could actually be argued to be less readable than inside a where statement, however I prefer the lack of subqueries, that's opinion based though and both methods will be planned without performance issue.

Also note that if you don't care about specifying the colors by ID you can remove a join:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM animals a
INNER JOIN animal_color ac ON (a.id = ac.animal_id AND ac.color_id IN (1, 2))
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ac.color_id) = 2
```

Comment: I'm looking for animal with black and white color.

Comment: This way I will be only able to select the name of an animal. What if I have more data and want  to select it as well? Also, grouping by name doesn't feel like the greatest idea. I can have two different animals with same name in theory.

Comment: Fair comment on grouping by name, changed to id. You can just append any more columns you want to select onto the list, for example `SELECT a.id AS animal_id, a.name AS animal, c.name AS color`

Comment: shouldn't it be `HAVING Count(DISTINCT ac.animal_id) = 2`

Comment: Counting distinct animal ids would remove the purpose of filtering by inner joining, as `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` returns the number of unique animal ids.

Comment: those queries will also select when there a two colors with id 1 and non with id 2 that's why i suggested `HAVING Count(DISTINCT ac.animal_id) = 2`

Comment: True, perhaps a `DISTINCT ac.color_id` would be good to alleviate that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if animal have 2 colors and those colors are white and black.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM animals a
JOIN animal_color c on c.animal_id = a.id
GROUP a.id, a.name
HAVING Count(color_id) = 2
   AND Count(CASE WHEN c.color_id IN (1,2) 
                  THEN 1 
              END) = 2
```

Comment: I feel like its' just a worse version of mine.

Comment: @RoboRobok Hey just trying to help. And worse is very subjective. Test it get an explain plan and then you can said if is worse.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Depend on the model. But I dont think they assign the same color twice to the animal.

Comment: To me it's overly complicated. I'd rather go with subquery that `CASE ... WHEN`. Plus, I complained about using "hardcoded" color counting in the query and this example uses it... twice.

Comment: What you mean hardcoded? You need to specify those values because that is what you are looking for.  Ultimate you are asking for help on how to do it. If you rather do a subquery then why you ask here? You already know there are different ways to do it most are very similar in performance.This fit my style and isnt complicated at all. Even is very easy to read in my opinion.

Comment: "Plus, I complained about using "hardcoded" color counting in the query and this example uses it... twice" i believe `Count(color_id) = 2
   AND Count(CASE WHEN c.color_id IN (1,2) 
                  THEN 1 
              END) = 2` can be replaced with only `Count(CASE WHEN c.color_id IN (1,2) 
                  THEN 1 
              END) = 2` @RoboRobok "Plus, I complained about using "hardcoded" color counting in the query" well it's not possible other wise.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solutions.

Selecting animals that are black&white, but also can have other colors:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   animals 
WHERE  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT colors.id) 
        FROM   colors 
               JOIN animal_color 
                 ON animal_color.color_id = colors.id 
        WHERE  animal_color.animal_id = animals.id 
               AND colors.name IN ( 'black', 'white' )) = 2
```

Selecting animals that are black&white only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   animals 
WHERE  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colors.name ORDER BY colors.name) 
        FROM   colors 
               JOIN animal_color 
                 ON animal_color.color_id = colors.id 
        WHERE  animal_color.animal_id = animals.id) = 'black,white'
```

As you see, I fetch by color, because it's more useful case sometimes. It's easi to change it to color ID.

Also, I can easily fetch any other data I want, because finding animals happens in `WHERE` clause only.

And finally, it works correctly with duplicated colors. Fetching black&white only requires script to sort needed colors alphabetically, but it's okay. I'm happy with relatively simple queries.